# What is that 3D software

Tags: design, software

I was wondering what is the 3D software being use ( picture below )
Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Please embed the image in your post instead of linking to an external site. That way your readers don't have to follow a link to understand your question and the question will still make sense when the link dies. Use the image upload button on the editor toolbar.

Comment: It looks like it could be Autodesk Maya.

Comment: Agreed, that was my first thought too, although zooming in it looks like the app icon us orangey, not the blue of Maya?

Comment: Based on logo on desktop: In house design software of Rivian.